# convergence of $\Sigma\frac{\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Investigate convergece of the following series: $$\frac{\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}} = \frac{\sqrt{n^2+3n+2}-\sqrt{n^2+n}}{n+1}$$
How to approach this?

Comment: but what next?? i know that the limit is zero but still this does not imply convergence thus i am looking for a comparison but i have no idea how to find good comparison

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{n+1}(\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n})}>\frac{1}{n+2}$$

So $\Sigma \frac{\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ diverges.

Comment: no doubt, best answer

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the [ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) to conclude that the series is divergent.